# SQL Server - setting 'Server-wide default logging level' results to error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014

I have this SSISDB catalog in SQL Server on which I want to set the 'Server-wide default logging level' on verbose (using the properties menu). This results into following error:

> ===================================
>
> Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.Catalog+LoggingLevelType'. (mscorlib)
>
> ---
>
> Program Location:
>
> at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)
>      at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
>      at System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.UITasks.PropertiesTask.UpdatePropertyGrid(Boolean& propertiesUpdated)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.UITasks.PropertiesTask.UpdateProperties()
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.UITasks.PropertiesTask.Perform(ITaskExecutionContext taskExecutionContext)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.TaskForms.TaskExecutionManager.ExecuteTaskSequence(ISfcScriptCollector collector)

This happens on any setting except for basic (default). Any sugestions/ideas?

Comment: It works fine for me, I'm guessing a permission issue is getting swallowed somewhere. Run the following command within SSMS `EXEC SSISDB.catalog.configure_catalog @property_name = N'SERVER_LOGGING_LEVEL', @property_value = 3;` I know some people that set their logging level to [Verbose](https://twitter.com/billinkc/status/694286656707305472) it got out of hand real fast.

Comment: Thanks, That command worked! I only need it temporarily, but I will keep your warning in mind :)